# Check compatibility of dynamic library at runtime

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

I am developing a C++ application which is required to load a dynamic library at runtime using dlopen. This library generally won't be written by me.

What method do people recommend to ensure future binary compatibility between this library and my application?

The options as I see them are:

1. Put the version number in the library file name, and attempt to load it (through a symbolic link) no matter what. If dlopen fails, report an error.
2. Maintain a second interface which returns an version number. However, if this interface changes for some reason, we run into the same problems as before.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a convention about the dynamically loaded (i.e. `dlopen`-ed) library.

You might have the convention that the library is required to provide a `const char mylib_version_str[];` symbol which gives the version of the API etc etc. Of course you could have your own preprocessor tricks to help about this.

For your inspiration, you might look at what GCC requires from its [plugins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugin-API.html#Plugin-API) (e.g. the `plugin_is_GPL_compatible` symbol).

If the dynamically loaded library is in C++, you might use [demangling](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) to check the signature of functions....

Comment: The beauty of this is that you don't need to run any code. So long as the library uses the right format - e.g. elf - you can read out any static strings. Consider someone loading a 64 bit lib on a 32-bit system. they can still read out the version information.

Comment: I am not sure that you can `dlopen` a 64 bit lib on a pure 32-bit system!

Answer (score 1):

why not use both options? by istance few libraries already do that (Lua for example, old dll is Lua51.dll, then you have Lua52 etc. nd you can also query its version.)

A good interface can change, but not so often, why should 2 simple static methods

```
const char* getLibraryName();
uint32 getLibraryVersion();
```

change overtime?

Answer (score 1):

if you/they are using a libtool to build a library/application you may recommend this way: http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Versioning

Comment: Add a small excerpt to your answer. Just linking is not considered a valid answer.